# Apply SELECT LEFT() on the total characters from multiple columns combined

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I wanted to limit the characters retrieved from a MySQL database and I know that LEFT() is the function to use. This is my query

```
SELECT id,
  LEFT(heading, 80) AS heading,
  LEFT(article, 20) AS article
FROM news
ORDER BY stamp DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

But actually what I want is to limit the total number of characters retrieved from the 'heading' and 'article' columns combined...

In other means; I always want the total to be 100 chars from both columns with priority to 'heading'... So, Mr. SQL, show 'heading' while you can (within the 100 chars range) and omit from 'article' as you wish, then if needed omit from 'heading' to reach the 100 chars condition.

i.e.
'heading' gives 80 chars and 'article' gives 120 chars, therefore, delete 100 chars from 'article'.

'heading' gives 110 chars and 'article' gives 500 chars, therefore, delete 500 chars from article and 10 chars from 'heading'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
  LEFT(heading, 100) AS heading,
  IF(LENGTH(heading)>=100, '', LEFT(article, 100-LENGTH(heading))) AS article
FROM news
ORDER BY stamp DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Obviously if you don't care about having it in 2 columns like your original query was, then use the `CONCAT` algorithm as the others mentionned.

Comment: Thank you very much, and yes I want it in two columns as my original query.

Comment: But why did you use substr() instead of LEFT(article, 100-LENGTH(heading))... Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,
  LEFT(CONCAT(heading, article), 100) AS heading_article
FROM news
ORDER BY stamp DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

This concats both columns and than get the `LEFT` 100 of the total Char, if you want a space character in between just do `CONCAT(heading, ' ', article)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I want it in two columns

Answer (score 0):

Use **[CONCAT()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)**

```
SELECT id,
  LEFT(concat(heading,article), 80) AS heading,
FROM news
ORDER BY stamp DESC
LIMIT 5;
```